# Complex Closed Loop Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $C$ be the boundary of the square whose sides lie along the lines $x = ±2$ and $y = ±2$,
described in the positive sense. What is the value of $$\int_C \frac{\cos{z}}{z(z^2+8)}dz$$

I parameterized $z = x+iy$ and substituted back into the equation.  This gives $\int_C \frac{\cos{(x+iy)}}{(x+iy)*((x+iy)^2+8)}dz$.  I split the square up into four sides, numbered 1,2,3, and 4.  Side 1 is the "right" side from $(2,-2)$ to $(2,2)$, side 2 the top side, and so forth.

I attempted to take the integral of side 1, using $x=2$ and $-2 <=y<=2$.  I ended up with $$i\int_C \frac{ \cos{(2+iy)}}{i(20y-y^3)-6y^2+24}dy$$ which would be a mess to integrate.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I think the only pole of your function inside $C$ is at $z=0$, so you could use the residue theorem?

Comment: @msteve I have been looking at the residue theorem online.  It is fairly confusing, but would it not come out to 0?  From what I can tell, using the residue theorem leads me to $Res(f,0) = lim(z)*f(z)$ as z approaches 0.

Comment: That's almost it - I've fleshed it out in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off my above comment, the only pole of the integrand $f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{z(z^2 + 8)}$ that lies inside $C$ is the simple pole at $z=0$. The residue theorem allows us to conclude that
$$
\int_C f(z) dz = 2\pi i \cdot \textrm{res}_{z=0} f(z),
$$
where 
$$
\textrm{res}_{z=0} f(z) := \lim_{z \to 0} (z-0) \cdot f(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2+8} = \frac{1}{8}.
$$
Therefore, $\int_C f(z) dz = \frac{\pi i}{4}$.

Comment: I see, I read the theorem wrong.  the $zf(z)$ makes a whole lot more sense than what I did.  Thanks.